# How do I build a query saying "get me all diplomas of which all steps are in this pivot table"?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models in my laravel project,  `Step`, `Diploma` and `Pupil`. This is what the relations look like:

```
class Pupil {
    function steps() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Step::class);
    }

    function diplomas() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Diploma::class);
    }
}

class Step {
    function diploma() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Diploma::class);
    }
}

class Diploma {
    function steps() {
        return $this->hasMany(Step::class);
    }
}
```

Now I have a form where the admin can check boxes of which steps a pupil has accomplished, which I then save by doing `$pupil->steps()->sync($request['steps']);`. Now what I want to do is find the diplomas of which all the steps have been accomplished and sync them too. But for some reason I can't figure out how to build that query. Is this clear? Would anyone like to help?

**edit** I now have this, but it's not as clean as I would like:

```
class Pupil {
    public function hasCompleted(array $completedSteps)
    {
        $this->steps()->sync($completedSteps);
        $diplomas = [];

        foreach(Diploma::all() as $diploma) {
            // First see how many steps does a diploma have...
            $c1 = Step::where('diploma_id', $diploma->id)->count();
            // Then see how many of those we completed
            $c2 = Step::where('diploma_id', $diploma->id)->whereIn('id', $completedSteps)->count();

            // If that's equal, then we can add the diploma.
            if ($c1 === $c2) $diplomas[] = $diploma->id;
        }

        $this->diplomas()->sync($diplomas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of syncing the diplomas, as the steps could change in the future, what about pulling the diplomas via the completed steps when you need to know the diplomas?

```
class Pupil {  

    public function hasCompleted(array $completedSteps) {
        $this->steps()->sync($completedSteps);
    }

    public function getCompletedDiplomas() {
        $steps = $this->steps;
        $stepIds = // get the step ids
        $diplomaIdsFromSteps = // get the diploma Ids from the $steps

        $potentialDiplomas = Diploma::with('steps')->whereIn('id', $diplomaIdsFromSteps)->get();

        $diplomas = [];

        foreach($potentialDiplomas as $d) {
            $diplomaSteps = $d->steps;
            $diplomaStepIds = // get unique diploma ids from $diplomaSteps
            if(/* all $diplomaStepIds are in $stepIds */) {
                $diplomas[] = $d;
            }

        }

        return $diplomas;

    }
}
```

I haven't completed all the code since I'm unable to test it right now.  However, I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer my way then. The steps to a diploma might change, but when someone obtains a diploma, s/he should keep that diploma. :-)

Comment: Wouldn't the code you have in your question would still remove a diploma if a new step was added? You might look into the attach() function instead of sync(). Best of luck!

Comment: True, although only during an update request. During a get request a diploma stays even if it doesn't meet all the steps. With your way, a diploma can unexpectedly not be assigned during a get-request because the pupil misses a new step.